# how to Bypass no value error (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

for Instance I'm trying to have two batch programs, one made from the other program. But they both suppose to edit another batch program but in that program it has to 1 variable set but it requires two and only when the 3rd program starts will the second one starts up and detects its data and add the second value to the 3rd program

Example of the 3rd program on its **first** start up:

```
@echo off
set a=1
goto a
*command*
:a
IF %b% EQU 3 GOTO section_3
if %a% EQU 2 goto section_2
:section_1
*command*
```

Example of the 3rd program on its **second** start up:

```
@echo off
set b=3
set a=1
goto a
*command*
:a
if %b% EQU 3 goto section_3
if %a% EQU 2 goto section_2
:section_1
*command*
```

*So my question is* how do i Bypass the " IF %b% EQU 3 GOTO section_3 " without editing the code and only adding to the code in between :a and " IF %b% EQU 3 GOTO section_3 "

Really appreciate this thanks!

Comment: What about inserting `if defined b goto :section_1` after `:a` to skip the `if %b% EQU 3` query in case `b` is empty, so avoiding the syntax error (same for `a`)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only allow code inserted directly after `:a` and don't specify what to do if `b` is not defined, I'll hazard a guess:

```
if not defined b if %a% equ 2 (goto section_2) else (goto section_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> So my question is how do i Bypass the " IF %b% EQU 3 GOTO section_3 " without editing the code and only adding to the code in between :a and " IF %b% EQU 3 GOTO section_3 "

but your tag list includes [syntax-error](/questions/tagged/syntax-error), so you really should be asking ***"How do I modify my code to avoid the syntax error at*** `if %b% EQU 3 goto section_3` ***when b is undefined"***

You are getting a syntax error, so of course you need to modify code. Your request to fix the bug without modifying the code makes no sense.

You get a syntax error when b is undefined because the IF statement is parsed after percent expansion, and the line expands to `if  EQU 3 goto section_3`, which is obviously a syntax error. One of the simplest and most common solutions to such a problem is to add quotes around both the left and right side of the comparison:

```
if "%b%" EQU "3" goto section_3
```

which safely expands to `if "" EQU "3" goto section_3` when b is undefined, and the IF statement is now syntactically correct.

But I believe you have much bigger problems. Using batch scripts to modify another batch script is *almost* always a bad idea, especially the way you have described your process. You haven't adequately described your true goal, so I can't suggest what you should be doing. But I can almost guarantee there is a better way to solve your problem that does not involve batch files modifying other batch files.